# Updating data in shiny app published on R studio Connect

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to use google sheets to access data in my shiny App which I have published to `R` Studio Connect. 
Does the data get fetched from google sheets every time the app is loaded? 
How can I access the latest data from google sheets in my shiny App?

Comment: Hi, I think that it depends on where (in which part of your app) you load the data - can you put the code where you load the data into your Shiny app?

Comment: I am loading  the data from google sheet at the beginning of the file using read_sheet()
gs4_auth()
df <- read_sheet("")

Comment: When you say "at the beginning of the file" which file do you mean? Shiny will run the `server.R` for every new session, while if you have a `global.R` or anything before the `shinyServer(function(input, output,session)` line in your `server.R` then all objects there are shared across sessions for each Shiny process. You can read more about scoping here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html

Comment: I have only one file App.R where I am accessing data from google sheets before ShinyServer().
By shared across sessions, you mean data will not be fetched every time I load my published app?

Comment: If that is the case, then no, you can't **guarantee** that the new file will be fetched **every** time, except when you start a new Shiny process to serve the app. If you have many users and the Shiny process on the Connect server never shuts down, then I think that the data will not be refreshed until the the process is shut down. If you want for every session to load the file anew then you can move the code that loads the data inside the `shinyServer` function. If it is a small dataset it won't be too much of a problem, but if it is large and you have many users that won't be too efficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.
Will try it out